# Perl: How to replace a variable by its value

Tags: regex, string, perl, perl-module

Suppose, if a table has a column called test and inside test I have written a row as **"Dear $name, Hello"** where $name is a variable. I need to select this row for which I'm doing

```
my $test = $dbh->prepare( "select test from testing")
```

In the script I have assigned **$name="Joe"** .
Now, I need to replace the **$name** variable with the variable name assigned in the script (i.e Joe). I tried printing $test. It prints "Dear $name, Hello"
How can I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
use strict;

my $name = "Joe";
my $test = 'Dear $name, Hello';

$test =~ s/\$name/$name/ ;

print $test;
```

Output:

```
Dear Joe, Hello
```

Comment: Nikhil, thanks for the reply it isnt working and is giving warning

Comment: @Vishu: can you mention the warning please?

Comment: In the question, you have mentioed $name, "n" is is lowercase but now looks like you are using different variable $Name, that's why you are getting warning. Please mention the exact code which you are using for figuring out the issue.

Comment: Use of uninitialized value $Name in regexp compilation-Im getting this warning

Comment: From the warning, i can say that you are using $Name variable directly without initializing it, so before using it declare it as my `$Name`, then it should not throw warning.

Comment: The row which I select from database has "Dear $Name, Hello". Now this needs to be replaced with the $name="Joe".

Comment: Do it like  `$test =~ s/\$Name/$name/ ;`

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you use the [`String::Interpolate`](https://metacpan.org/module/String::Interpolate) module, which applies Perl's own interpolation system to values you pass by parameter. It will probably need to be installed from CPAN as it is not a core module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use String::Interpolate 'interpolate';

my $name = "Joe";

my $text = 'Dear $name, Hello';
print interpolate($text);
```

**output**

```
Dear Joe, Hello
```

Comment: Borodin, thanks for the quick reply. But my concern is I need to replace the variable taken from row in the database.

Comment: @Vishu: what Borodin posted enables you to do exactly that.